# JavaFX MenuList with different colors

Tags: java, javafx, import

I'm trying to create a menu list with different colors with the javafx.scene.paint.Color import. When I create the list I want to be able to select a color and be able to change the color of the object while the program runs. I'm not sure what the best way to set this up is. Do i manually have to create a menu for each color with a string and assign a color or is there a more time efficient way? Thanks!

Comment: The standard tutorial has an example of a [`ListView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/list-view.htm#CEGGEDBF) that displays a list of colors for selection. (You can easily do the same with a combo box.) Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yeah I think this will work. Thanks James!